# Lightdm logon problems

Tags: raspbian

I  installed htpcguides media centre image on paspberry pi 2 and then elected to install lightdm and auto logon. All works fine in console but lightdm just continuoly ask for user and password. No combination of old or new users work.
I did change user and passwords as instructed, but lightdm accepts nothing as being correct